# Solution of $\int_a^b f(z)g(z)dz=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

Fix $a\in[0,1]$ and let $b$ an arbitraty value in $[a,1]$. Moreover, there is a positive and continuous function $g:[0,1]\rightarrow(0,\infty)$.

I want to find a solution $f$ of

$$\int_a^bf(z)g(z)dz=0$$

Obviously I can pick $f=0$, but is there another solution?

**EDIT:** Actually I want to find $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, that solves following integral:

$$x=\int_{a_1}^x\exp\Big(-2\int_{a_2}^yg(z)f(z)dz\Big)dy$$

where $a_1,a_2\in[0,1]$ and a continuous $g:[0,1]\rightarrow(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Hm, I just realised, I can differentiate again. This would give $f(b)g(b)=0$ and therefore $f(b)=0$, right?

Comment: It depends on what the question means.  Do you want an $f$ that works for every $b \in [a,1]$, or an $f$ that works for one $b$?

Comment: You cannot differentiate again! The left hand side is a number (okay, it is in terms of a and b, but they are fixed and you can’t change them).

Comment: @RobertIsrael I understand that both a and b are given arbitrary numbers.

Comment: I did an edit to my question. I was differentiating both sides and applying $log$, which gave me the integral I mentioned first. But this might have been a mistake.

Comment: f only has to be zero if $f: [0,1] \rightarrow (0,\infty)$ right? how do you conclude it has to be ALWAYS zero ?

Comment: only $g$ has to have image in $(0,\infty)$

Comment: Your integral equation in the edit has a unique solution $f\equiv 0$ along with $a_1=0$.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee: Why is this solution unique? It is clear to me that it is an solution, but how can I verify uniqueness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $h : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and solves

$$ x = \int_{a_1}^{x} \exp\biggl(-2\int_{a_2}^{y} h(z)\, \mathrm{d}z \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}y $$

for some $a_1, a_2 \in [0, 1]$. (In OP's case, we have $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$.) Then by plugging $x = a_1$, we find that $a_1 = 0$. Next, differentiating both sides w.r.t. $x$,

$$ 1 = \exp\biggl(-2\int_{a_2}^{x} h(z)\, \mathrm{d}z \biggr) $$

and so, it follows that

$$ \int_{a_2}^{x} h(z)\, \mathrm{d}z = 0 $$

for all $x \in [0, 1]$. Differentiating both sides w.r.t. $x$ again, we have $h \equiv 0$.

Answer (score 0):

For fixed $a$ and $b$ the basic approach seems fairly simple, assuming $f(x)$ does not have to integrable.. Let $c=(a+b)/2$.  Then for $a\le x\lt c$, let $f(x)=1/g(x)$, while for $c\le x\le b$ let $f(x)=-1/g(x)$.

The only difficulty would be where $g(x)=0$ over an interval. Here that interval would be excluded and the rest of the domain split as above.